# Visualization of $L(X)$

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, random-variable, measure-theory, random-vector

Let $L^2_+$ the set of all $2$-dimensional nonnegative random vectors $X = (X_1, X_2)^⊤$ with finite and positive marginal expectations, and let $Ψ^{(2)}$ the class of all measurable functions from $\Bbb R^2_+$ to $[0, 1].$ Then $L(X)$ of the random vector $X$ with joint CDF $F$ is:

$$L(X)=\bigg\{\bigg(\int \psi(x)dF(x), \int \frac{x_1\psi(x)}{E(X_1)}dF(x),\int \frac{x_2\psi(x)}{E(X_2)}dF(x):\psi \in Ψ^{(2)}\bigg)\bigg\}. $$

Here $L(X)$ is a convex subset of the unit $3-$cube including the points $(0,0,0)$ and $(1,1,1).$

I have a few questions but one can be answered:

> Is there an analytic representation of $L(X)?$

> Can anyone make a visualization/plot of $L(X)$?

> Is there a definition of $L(X)$ expressed in the language of differential geometry, i.e. without using random vectors/distributions?

Could a definition be found using the theory of the majorization partial order on finite sets on $\Bbb R^n?$