# generalization of univariate pdf under constraints

Tags: multivariate-analysis, marginal-distribution, multivariate-distribution

I'm looking for generalizations of a univariate probability distribution function. The pdf is $$ \varphi(x)=(2\sqrt{s}K_1(2\sqrt{s}))^{-1}e^{\frac{s}{\log x}}. $$

for $K_1$ a modified Bessel function, and $0<x<1$.

There are several, fairly trivial options for a generalization, but I have some particular constraints. Specifically I need the marginal distributions of the multivariate generalization, $\varphi(x,y),$ to be $\varphi(x)$ and $\varphi(y)$ respectively. Furthermore I require $\varphi(0,1)=1$ and $\varphi(1,0)=0.$ Last requirement is that $\varphi(x,y)$ must be closed (a surface that is compact and without boundary). I realize that $\varphi(0,1)=1$ and $\varphi(1,0)=0$ may be slightly problematic because the marginals  are undefined at two singular points due to the logarithm, however I simply only care that the surface is defined near these points for some neighborhood around $(0,1,1)$ and $(1,0,0).$

The natural support for both the marginals is the interval $(0,1)$ and I wish to preserve this in the generalization, meaning that the closed surface, should have support on $(0,1)^2$ and be a subset of $(0,1)^3.$

Comment: Use *any* smooth copula you like.

Comment: could you give me a simple example of one? I'm not super familiar with copulas

Comment: Sure: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=copula.

Comment: Please make an answer to this question if you wish

Comment: I'm not sure how *any* smooth copula would satisfy my requirements

Comment: I don't understand why you might impose such requirements or even if they are mathematically possible.  Your meaning of "closed" is mysterious because there is no way the full graph of $\phi$ can be compact and, if you were to restrict it to the domain $(0,1)\times(0,1)$ (or even its closure) there's no way it could not have a boundary.  Thus, I have discounted all these conditions and pointed to a way to generate any multivariate generalization you like.

Comment: I know for sure that it's mathematically possible I just haven't been able to show it yet because it's highly nontrivial. Only recently were Koshevoy and Mosler able to achieve the "Lorenz Zonoid" (1995) which is a specific generalization of the Lorenz curve to $n-$dimensions, where one gets convex Lorenz surfaces as subsets of the $n-$cube. It's surfaces like this that I want to construct as a generalization of the $\varphi(x)$ distriubtion

Comment: I can edit the post to include the relevance of this to The Lorenz zonoid $L(\mathbf X)$ if it's appropriate

Comment: here is a link to the Koshevoy approach: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/574171/visualization-of-lx